Find the smallest integer $n$ such that $n^2 +n > 20$.
I'm trying to find the smallest integer $n$ that satisfies the inequality $n^2 + n > 20$.
I started by rewriting the inequality as:
$$n^2 + n - 20 > 0$$
Next, I solved the quadratic equation $n^2 + n - 20 = 0$ using the quadratic formula:
$$
n = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 80}}{2}
$$
This gave me the roots:
$$
n = 4 \quad \text{and} \quad n = -5
$$
After checking the values:

For $n = 4$:
$$
  4^2 + 4 = 20 \quad (\text{not greater than } 20)
  $$

For $n = -5$:
$$
  (-5)^2 + (-5) = 20 \quad (\text{not greater than } 20)
  $$


I also checked $n = 5$ and found:

For $n = 5$:
$$
  5^2 + 5 = 30 \quad (\text{greater than } 20)
  $$

However, I realized that I missed checking negative integers lower than $-5$. When I checked $n = -6$:

For $n = -6$:
$$
  (-6)^2 + (-6) = 36 - 6 = 30 \quad (\text{greater than } 20)
  $$

Now, I am unsure about how to conclude. Based on my calculations, it seems that the smallest integer satisfying $n^2 + n > 20$ could actually be a very big negative number instead of $n = 5$.
Can someone confirm whether my understanding is correct or what I'm missing?

If negative integers are allowed, there is no "smallest" integer.

This question needs context. Where did this come from to start?

Yeah, you want to edit this to say smallest positive integer, or non-negative, I think.

@lulu I have always used the term "less than", not "smaller than", for the symbol $<$. The problem with using "smaller than" for $<$ is that some people use "large" to mean "far from zero" and "small" to mean "close to zero". See https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/13680 and https://english.stackexchange.com/q/357736/82116. According to some peoples' usage, $-1$ is the smallest negative integer and there is no largest negative integer.

@DavidK  I agree.  I only used "smallest" because the OP did.  Of course, I took it to mean "least", not "closest to $0$".

@lulu OP did use "smallest". My response would be that this is ambiguous. I would not disambiguate it by interpreting it as "least." For the same reason, I would not interpret it as "closest to zero." I would ask for more context and clarity.

@DavidK  Oh, I disagree.  There is no ambiguity here.  The OP clearly states " Based on my calculations, it seems that the smallest integer satisfying $n^2+n>20$
could actually be a very big negative number instead of $n=5$."  So, while I agree that the terminology is sloppy, I think the intended meaning is entirely clear.
.

@lulu It is clear how OP interpreted the question. How do we know OP is reading the problem correctly?  I would ask for more context and clarity. In the context where this problem came up (a course of study, presumably), how was the word "smallest" used previously? Are there previous examples where, for example, $-7$ was considered "smaller" than $-6$?

Because in the context OP is assuming, this question makes no sense, but in another context, it is a perfectly sensible, answerable question and the answer is $5$.

@DavidK Fair enough.  Though my guess is that the problem really specified "natural numbers" or something like that.  But, of course, if they truly meant "smallest" in the sense of "least absolute value", then you get the same result, namely $n=5$.   Coincidence, of course.

@lulu OK. My guess about the intent of the original problem is the same as yours. All interpretations that admit a negative solution appear less likely to be the original intent.

The inequality can be written as
$$
(n+5)(n-4) > 0
$$
The solution for the above inequality is $(-\infty,-5) \cup (4,\infty)$ which not bounded. So there is no smallest integer.
